# R Shiny: test existence of reactive value which is optional after req()

Tags: r, shiny

I have code like this

```
myfx <- reactive({
  req(
    isTruthy(input$value),
    isTruthy(data1()) || isTruthy(data2())
  )
  ...
  
  if(exists(data2())) {
    # do some stuff
  }
  ## do this other stuff regardless 
})
```

The `if(exists())` piece is where I am stuck. Exists is not the right function here, nor does `validate(need(data2()))` work. How can I conditionally execute some code if one of the optional reactives (from a group where at least one is required) exists?

**EDIT 1**: To make explicit the problem, see the issue illustrated by the debug prints below:

```
myfx <- reactive({
  req(
    isTruthy(input$value),
    isTruthy(data1()) || isTruthy(data2())
  )
  
  print("I am printed, and data2() has not been uploaded by user")
  print(isTruthy(data2()))
  print("I am never printed")

  if(isTruthy(data2())) {
    # do some stuff
  }
  ## do this other stuff regardless 
})
```

**Edit 2:** ok I see the reason. And I also see that I'm not observing the behavior in my first `req()` call because of short-circuiting (||). But now I'm stuck how to achieve the behavior I want. Bascially I don't calculate data2() until the user uploads something (use a `req()` here too). So that is where this is hanging. But if I remove the `req()` from the top of this, then I get errors due to trying to work on input that doesn't exist. See the definition for data2() below. How can I fix this?

```
data2 <- reactive({
    req(input$data2)

    read.csv(input$data2$datapath) %>%
        as_tibble() %>%
        return()
})
```

Comment: Can you provide a small example to try out some possibilities? On first pass, it seems like `if(isTruthy(data2())) {}` should do it, but I'm guessing you already tried that...

Comment: I'll work on a reprex, but yes that is the first thing I tried. What I observe is that the evaluation now passes the req() statements, but stops and waits at the if(isTruthy(... I also entered print(isTruthy(data2() ) ) before the if() statement and it then pauses here if data2() has no value. data2() comes from a user-file upload which will be optional.

Comment: Glad you figured out an answer, but the example wasn't particularly helpful because I still couldn't run anything...hard to work with reactivity outside of an actual app.

Comment: I agree w u, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is the final working solution.

```
myfx <- reactive({
  req(
    isTruthy(input$value),
    isTruthy(data1()) || isTruthy(data2())
  )
  
  print("I am printed, and data2() has not been uploaded by user")
  print(isTruthy(data2()))
  print("I am never printed")

  if(isTruthy(data2())) {
    # do some stuff
  }
  ## do this other stuff regardless 
})


data2 <- reactive({
    if(isTruthy(input$data2)) {
        read.csv(input$data2$datapath) %>%
          as_tibble() %>%
          return()
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can re-use `isTruthy`. Since it still returns true for 0 rows, you may want to add a check for non-zero row count:

```r
myfx <- reactive({
  req(
    isTruthy(input$value),
    isTruthy(data1()) || isTruthy(data2())
  )
  ...
  
  if (isTruthy(data2()) && nrow(data2()) > 0) {
    # do some stuff
  }
  ## do this other stuff regardless 
})
```

Or you can capture the attempt in a `try`/`tryCatch` and react accordingly:

```r
myfx <- reactive({
  req(
    isTruthy(input$value),
    isTruthy(data1()) || isTruthy(data2())
  )
  ...

  res2 <- tryCatch({
    # do some stuff with data2()
  }, error = function(e) NULL)
  
  ## do this other stuff regardless 
})
```

Comment: see my clarifying Edit to OP

Comment: the second part works with tryCatch. Couldn't get the first part to work

Answer (score 0):

1. raise an error if dat2 doesn't exit by checking number of rows
2. chk will become NULL if dat2 doens't exist
3. use chk in if statement to determine what to do

   ```
   chk <- tryCatch({ nrow(dat2()) > 0}, error = function(e) NULL)

   if(is.null(chk)){
     dat1
   } else{
     cbind(dat1, dat2)
   }
   ```